# LED driver as Power source

Tags: led-driver

I am beginner in electronics, I have LED driver (12V 5A) can I use it as power source for DC motors,Small DIY projects,or as SMPS?

Comment: Yes. It will likely be simplest if it's a constant voltage source than were it a constant current.

Comment: We can't answer that as you don't provide information what kind of LED driver you have. If the output is unisolated then definitely no as it's dangerous.

Comment: @Justme: what kind of regulated commercial DC supply isn't isolated?

Comment: @dandavis who said it is a regulated commercial DC supply? All we know it is an unknown 12V 5A LED driver, and many LED drivers are meant to be used inside a lamp where nobody touches it.

Comment: @dandavis *what kind of regulated commercial DC supply isn't isolated?* many cheap ones intended for driving LEDs that are simply unisolated buck regulators. Never assume that a supply is isolated until you're sure that it is.

Comment: How does OP know the specs? Internal proprietary drivers don't often have spec labels. Since V+I are given, and V is not a range, it sounds like a common 12v DC power supply. A picture would be worth all our speculation, but odds are good that it's isolated. Give it the old finger test if in doubt. How generous they were with the kapton between windings is another matter, and I would be willing to doubt the _quality_ of the isolation.